# time complexity issue when i am exporting sentinel image to gcp bucket

Tags: sentinel-2, google, cloud-gis, ground-control

`Export.map.toCloudStorage({ image: visImage, description: dist_name + '_' + img_type, bucket: 'up-amnex-earth-engine', fileFormat: 'auto', path : 'agrogate_v2', maxZoom: 16, region: dist, writePublicTiles: true, bucketCorsUris: ['https://code.earthengine.google.com','https://*.earthengine.app'] });`

Comment: Welcome to GIS Stack Exchange. Coding questions require sharing the code. Kindly share it.